# How to get metadata of JsTree items from contextmenu?

Tags: jstree

In `jstree` , I can right click on a node and select an item from the context menu.
In the code below, I am trying to use the `obj` object to get the tree item. I can get that using `$(obj)` however this is just a HTML list item. How do I get metadata (foo) associated with that ?

```
    $(element).jstree(
     "data" : { "data" : {"title" : "An item"}, "metadata":{"foo" :"bar"}},
     "plugins" : ["themes",  "ui", "contextmenu"],
     "contextmenu" : {

      "items" : function($node) {
           return {
             "Menu1" : function(obj){
                 //my menu action
               }         
         };
     };
    }

 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how the metadata can be accessed.

```
obj.data().foo
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, when trying to fetch the ID of a selected jsTree node.

[image]

It can be done, you just need to create your own function to populate the contextmenu, to fetch the relevant values from your JSON data:

[jsTree Context Menu selected item?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10481773/jstree-context-menu-selected-item/25115210#25115210)

Answer (score 0):

In arguments of function `contextmenu.items` you have access of current item data. This dynamically invocable function, fired every time on new right click event on node, See example:

```
$('#post-tree').jstree({
  core: {
    data: treeData
  },
  plugins: ['contextmenu'],
  contextmenu: {
    items: function (item) {

      return {
        addPost: {
          label: 'Add new Post',
          action: function () {
            console.log(item.original); // metadata object
          }
        },
        addSubcategory: {
          label: 'Add subcategory',
          action: function () {
            console.log('addSubcategory');
          }
        },
        editCategory: {
          label: 'Properties',
          action: function () {
            console.log('editCategory')
          }
        },
        delete: {
          label: 'Delete',
          action: function () {
            console.log('delete Category');
          }
        }
      };

    }
  }
});
```